# Laptop battery is charging, system says it is not

Tags: battery, opensuse

This happens when I turn on my laptop without the power cord plugged in, then plug in after it is on. The battery is charging, the system reports the battery level and I can see it increasing, but it says the battery is "discharging" and the energy saving mode is at "battery mode" instead of "on AC power".

If I turn on the laptop with the power cord plugged in, it correctly reports the battery as "charging" and uses "on AC power" energy saving mode.

If I unplug it, it correctly identifies it is unplugged and discharging, so at least some battery events are working.

I'm using opensuse tumbleweed with the default power management utilities.

Laptop model: Samsung NP500R5H-YD1BR

Comment: You have to reset the power manager of the laptop. Which model is the laptop? (I'm assuming both the battery and the cord is working properly)

Comment: @TDK I added the laptop model to the question: Samsung NP500R5H-YD1BR

Comment: @TDK This laptop has a sealed battery, I cannot remove it